# Cannot find/download .csr file from Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

I am new to Intel XDK and have developed iOS app. I am trying to deploy the iOS app using Intel XDK. I need a CSR file for it. I am trying to generate CSR file using Intel XDK. But I cannot download the generated CSR file anywhere. I searched my local system and also can't find any such files.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate .csr file from intel xdk. fill in the details and click submit. wait for some time to complete the process then it will show pop up to download the file to desired location. try and if you have any other problem reply.

Comment: After i clicked submit i get 

<

Now, you'll need to use the Apple Developer site to generate a certificate using your Certificate Signing Request. After you've got your certificate file, return here and click "Next." 

For help on creating a certificate, please see the Intel XDK documentation.



>

But i cannot download anything.

Comment: I dont understand. what do you get when you click submit?

Comment: After submitting the details there is no any download option

Comment: This may be some bug in intel xdk. after you click submit the pop up shows "getting certificate sign in request. please wait". Then it will pop up file explorer to download the the certificate. try restarting the intel xkd. Are you using mac?

Comment: I am using win10. I am updating intel xdk now. It might be due to that

Comment: That may be the problem. even though intel xdk is good tool it has lot of bugs to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I get this image but no any download option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should get when you click submit.[image]
after that you will get this pop up. I you are not getting these it should be a bug in intel xdk. [image]